# Сортировка массивов по возрастанию

Tags: javascript, массивы, сортировка

Привет, помогите пожалуйста с задачей, код есть но я неверно в нём что-то прописал. Надо чтобы происходила сортировка по возрастанию ядер (cores)

```js
let arr = [
    {cpu: 'Intel',
     info: {cores: 2,
            cache: 3
        }},
    {cpu: 'Intel',
        info: {cores: 4,
            cache: 4
        }},
    {cpu: 'amd',
        info: {cores: 1,
            cache: 1
        }},
    {cpu: 'Intel',
        info: {cores: 3,
            cache: 2
        }},
    {cpu: 'amd',
        info: {cores: 4,
            cache: 2
        }},
]

function sortByCores() {
    arr.sort(( prev, next ) => prev.cores - next.cores);
    return arr;
}
```

Comment: `prev.info.cores`. Ну и c `next` аналогично.

Answer (score 2):

```js
let arr = [
  {
    cpu: 'Intel',
    info: {cores: 2,cache: 3
    }
  },
  {
    cpu: 'Intel',
    info: {cores: 4,cache: 4
    }
  },
  {
    cpu: 'amd',
    info: {cores: 1, cache: 1
    }
  },
  {
    cpu: 'Intel',
    info: {cores: 3, cache: 2
    }
  },
  {
    cpu: 'amd',
    info: {cores: 4, cache: 2
    }
  },
]

function sortByCores() {
  arr.sort((a, b) =>  a.info.cores - b.info.cores);
  return arr;
}
sortByCores();
console.log(arr);
```

Answer (score 1):

У тебя ошибка в работе с объектами. У тебя в каждом объекте, которые ты получаешь в sort, есть только два поля cpu и info. А в info еще два поля cores и cache. Следовательно функция сортировки должна выглядеть так:

`arr.sort(( prev, next ) => prev.info.cores - next.info.cores);`